# Why User.Identity.GetUserId() Web Api 2 method is not working with myController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I have 2 controller

1. AccountController //api controller
2. MyController //normal controller

> When I call api controller (Account controller), I can get an `UserID`. Which means user logged In already, still not yet logged out

```
[Authorize]
[Route("ShowMessage")]
public string GET()
{
    string id;
    id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UserID = " + id);
    return "Success";
}
```

I am calling above code using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Account/ShowMessage',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success login data');

    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log('Login Failed');
    }
});
```

> when User call another view **MyAccount.cshtml**. it will check again UserID exists or not in `MyAccount()` action method, but throws `null`

```
public ActionResult MyAccount()
{
    string UserID = "";
    if (User.Identity.GetUserId() == null)                 // throws null
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("userID is null");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        // my code...
    }
}
```

Api GET() method can get the `UserID`, which means still `Token` is valid. But why from my normal controller cannot get `UserID`

**NOTE**

> Once I clear cookies from browser and again login, then both api and my controller get an UserID

**UPDATE**

> If I add `[Authorize]` on `ActionResult MyAccount()` method, It shows 401 error. But at the same time, when I call ajax to web API controller `GET()` method, it shows userID.

So how it works?.

Comment: Try adding `[Authorize]` on the other controller (or action). You are not telling MVC that you expect a logged in user.

Comment: @BennyM the first calling `api controller action` with bearer + token for authorization purpose. but the second normal controller for authentication purpose. Here authorization is success, which means still token is still valid in api controller. but `MyAccount()` action method failed to get userid when still token is valid,